# Uniform distribution and discrete distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \{1,...,n\}$ discrete random variable with every point having same probability. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
What is $Z = X + Y$?

My failed attempt: $F(X+Y) =  Pr(X+Y < x + y) = Pr(X<x)P(Y<y) = X \dfrac {y}{n} $.

It seems obvious to me that for example if person A picks whole number, and person B selects the number on the interval from $(0,1)$ the probablity of selecting a certain number has the same probability than selecting another one.

However, I would need more formal description of that. How does the expected value of $E(X+Y)$ look like?

Comment: $\mathbf{E}[X+Y]$ is a number, not a distribution, and it's equal to the sum of expectations, which are easy to find.

Comment: There are several absurd notations in your post, which textbook are you following?

Comment: I made this exercise myself, therefore it seems absurd.

Comment: For example, what do you try to say with F(X+Y)=F(X+Y<x+y)?

Comment: @Did it was a typo. I wanted to use the definition of Comulative distribution function.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of F(X+Y)=P(X+Y<x+y)? And of P(X<x)=X? And...

Comment: @Did It is obvious that I defined F(z) totally uncorrect. P is Pr. and... I am sorry for my post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$F(z)=\Pr(Z \le z) = \Pr(Y \lt \lfloor z \rfloor) + \Pr(Y = \lfloor z \rfloor, X \le z-\lfloor z \rfloor)$$ where  $\lfloor z \rfloor$ is the floor function giving the largest integer less than or equal to $z$.

If $y=\lfloor z \rfloor$ so an integer, and $x=z-\lfloor z\rfloor$ so in $[0,1)$ then you can rewrite this as $$F(z) = \Pr(Y \lt y) + \Pr(Y = y, X \le x) = \frac{y-1}{n} + \frac1n \times x = \frac{z-1}{n}$$ for $1 \le z \lt n+1$, and this indicates that $Z$ is uniformly distributed.